# Destructruing and comparing data in efficient way

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure trying my hands on with different "destructing" in clojure.
So what am I trying to achieve here is, I have two data-set like in below code snippet :- Major & minor,

```
(def result {"Major" { [200 {1 5,2 6, 3 4}] [ 201 {1 5,2 10,4 10,6 10}]}
             "Minor" { [ 200 {1 5,2 6,3 4,4 10}] [ 201 {1 5,2 10,3 10}]}})
```

I want to take each of minor's data-set entry and compare it with its corresponding major data-set entry, if the value of the major data-set entry is sub-set of the minor one, then delete that entry from both the data-set (i.e major and minor).Else assoc that entry in some other var (i.e **major-only** & **minor-only**). And vice versa.

For example:-

`{"Major" { [200  {1 5,2 10, 3 10}] [201 {1 5,2 10,4 10,6 10}] [204 {1 4,2 5,3 8,4 9}]}
"Minor" { [200 {1 5,2 10,3 10,4 10}] [203 {1 5,2 10,3 10}] [204 {1 4,2 5,3 8}]}})`

- `major-only` will be:- `{201 value}` (because it doesn't exists in minor), `{204 value}` (since the major's value is not subset of minor's value for key 204)
- `minor-only` will be:-`{203 value}` (Since it does not exists in major),`{204 value}` entry(because the subset condition failed)

I tried to perform `reduce` with `update-in` while destructuring and comparing the data, but couldn't get the efficient way to get the expected result. Can anyone assist me here?

Also, i want to return the result of the function as below:-

{`:major-only` major-only
`:minor-only` minor-only}, how can I return this type of value?

Comment: Can you clarify why `204` should appear in `minor-only`? `Minor`'s `240` entry appears to be a subset of `Major`'s `204`.

Comment: @exupero:- You can assume "Major" as a main dataset, so when we are iterating `minor` over `major` then only we will check for the subset ( for a particular key, major's value is subset or not for minor's value for the same key). That is why in `major "204"` entry has some more value than the `minor`'s 204 entry, so that entry will stay in both the data-set. I hope this clears your doubt. Thanks for the help.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure all of your rules are completely clear to me, but here's a stab at an implementation of the sort of function you describe.

First, I'd define a `map-subset?` function:

```
(defn map-subset? [m1 m2]
  (and (<= (count m1) (count m2))
       (every?
         (fn [[k v]]
           (and (contains? m2 k)
                (= (m2 k) v)))
         m1)))
```

That might not be exactly what you mean by "subset", so feel free to adapt it accordingly.

Here's your data. I removed the square brackets around pairs in the map, since your question uses invalid EDN, and I assume this is what you meant:

```
(def data {"Major" {200 {1 5, 2 10, 3 10}
                    201 {1 5, 2 10, 4 10, 6 10}
                    204 {1 4, 2 5, 3 8, 4 9}}
           "Minor" {200 {1 5, 2 10, 3 10, 4 10}
                    203 {1 5, 2 10, 3 10}
                    204 {1 4, 2 5, 3 8}}})
```

The core function, then, is relatively simple:

```
(let [{:strs [Major Minor]} data]
  {:major-only (into {}
                     (remove (fn [[k v]]
                               (map-subset? v (Minor k))))
                     Major)
   :minor-only (into {}
                     (remove (fn [[k v]]
                               (map-subset? v (Major k))))
                     Minor)})
```

This rebuilds each map, removing entries whose values are subsets of the corresponding value in the other map:

```
{:major-only {201 {1 5, 2 10, 4 10, 6 10}
              204 {1 4, 2 5, 3 8, 4 9}}
 :minor-only {200 {1 5, 2 10, 3 10, 4 10}
              203 {1 5, 2 10, 3 10}}}
```

This produces slightly different results than in your example, which is why I'm not entirely sure if I understand your requirements, since from my interpretation of map subsets, Major's 200 is a subset of Minor's 200, and Minor's 204 is a subset of Major's 204.